# How to get to edX LMS side?

Tags: edx, openedx

I have a self-hosted installation of Open Edx, and have created a superuser.  How do I access the lms to create/edit course content?

oeu
oeu
oe
uo
eu
ouuoeuoeuoe

Answer (score 0):

To create courses/content you have to login into STUDIO, the default url is :18010, if you have a super user account you can create and edit courses from that platform.

Hope this solve your problem.
Regards.